# Azure Web-Jobs file not working (Job failed due to exit code -532462766)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

An exe file that runs on a schedule using quartz .net runs without problems on the local computer, but when it is loaded into Azure Web Jobs, its execution ends with an error (Job failed due to exit code -532462766). What can be wrong?

```
[01/15/2019 07:00:44 > 909db9: SYS INFO] Run script 'CurrencyUpdate.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[01/15/2019 07:00:44 > 909db9: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Default Quartz.NET properties loaded from embedded resource file
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for object serializer
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.5.0.0 created.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.5.0.0) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   Scheduler class: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   NOT STARTED.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   Currently in standby mode.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   Number of jobs executed: 0
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO]   Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.5.0.0
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] 1/15/2019 7:00:45 AM [INFO]  Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[01/15/2019 07:00:45 > 909db9: INFO] StartUpdate
[01/15/2019 07:00:46 > 909db9: INFO] EXMO UPDAte compltete
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ] 
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter value '12149703521483100.0000' is out of range.
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(SqlCommand cmd, _SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
[01/15/2019 07:00:56 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at CurrencyUpdate.Program.CurrencyUpdate.<Quartz-IJob-Execute>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Nexgen\source\repos\CurrencyUpdate\CurrencyUpdate\Program.cs:line 1891
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: ERR ]    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
[01/15/2019 07:00:57 > 909db9: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

At start, on the local computer, no errors occur. Publication ontakes place through Microsoft Visual Studo 2017.

Comment: Check the exception. "Parameter value '12149703521483100.0000' is out of range." If this is the case, this will fail when running locally or in the cloud. Please provide code, data, and more details.

Comment: The mistake was in incorrect formatting of the Decimal due to a culture that differs from the culture of the application on the local computer. The error has been fixed. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, this error was not particular to azure-webjobs. It was a culture mismatch between the local dev machine and the cloud instance in which the webjob ran.

The OP already fixed the issue.